# Frustrating code gives me strange output, maybe due to WRITE and READ?

Tags: integer, fortran, gfortran

This is a longer code that im having trouble with, and i think it is because im not sure i am fully understanding line `WRITE(6,*) 'INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU'` and `READ(5,*) S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU`. If I simply run the .f file  I get

`executable.exe 
INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU`

Then I enter the following inputs

`100.0d0,100.0d0,3.0d0,0.2d0,0.08d0,0.04d0,0.03d0`

After I do this I get a new file in my directory called "fort.2".  I don't know where in the code this is said to be produced ? Since if I change

```
WRITE(2,10) T(I),BD(I)
```

to

```
WRITE(3,10) T(I),BD(I)
```

I still get the file "fort.2". Anyhow I am suspicious of "fort.2" to be the correct output since, inside it there  are two columns (1) the values of  `T(I)` and values of (2) `BD(I)` . The first column is correct  `T(I)` changing with `0.03d0` steps up to `3.0d0` , this comes from `DTAU, TAU` . However `BD(I)` does not change for each `0.03d0` step, it is constant for several `0.03d0` steps and then suddenly changes (like a step function).  `BD(I)` is supposed to change for every `3.0d0` step. Right now i don't know I'm kinda lost. Main code:

```
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER MS,NS,JS,N,I
      PARAMETER(MS=50000,NS=50000)
      REAL*8 S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,SMIN,SMAX,DTAU,ALPHA,BETA,LAM
      REAL*8 V(0:MS),BD(0:NS),T(0:NS)
      COMMON/OUTPUT/V,BD,T

      WRITE(6,*) 'INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU'
      READ(5,*) S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU

      N = TAU/DTAU
      ALPHA = 2.0D0*R/SIGMA**2
      BETA = 2.0D0*(R-DELTA)/SIGMA**2
      LAM = (BETA-1.0D0) + DSQRT((BETA-1.0D0)**2+4.0D0*ALPHA)
      LAM = LAM/2.0D0
      SMIN = K/(1.0D0+1.0D0/LAM)               ! PERPETUAL BOUNDARY
      SMAX = 10.0D0*K
      CALL EXP_DIFF(S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,SMAX,SMIN,DTAU,JS)

      WRITE(6,*) 'PRICE: ', V(JS)
      DO I = 0, N
       WRITE(2,10) T(I),BD(I)
      ENDDO
10    FORMAT(1X,2F14.8)

      STOP
      END


C=======================================================================
      SUBROUTINE EXP_DIFF(S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,SMAX,SMIN,DTAU,JS)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER MS,NS,JS,M,N,I,J,IEARLY
      PARAMETER(MS=50000,NS=50000)
      REAL*8 S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,XMIN,XMAX,DTAU,DX,ALPHA,SMIN,SMAX,
     &       P1,P2,P3,VC,A,B
      REAL*8 VE(0:MS),V(0:MS),BD(0:NS),T(0:NS)
      COMMON/OUTPUT/V,BD,T

      IF (S.GT.SMAX) THEN
       STOP 'THE OPTION IS WORHTLESS'
      ENDIF

      IF (S.LT.SMIN) THEN
       STOP 'THE OPTION WORTHS K-S FOR CERTAIN'
      ENDIF

      XMIN = DLOG(SMIN)
      XMAX = DLOG(SMAX)
      DX = SIGMA*DSQRT(3.0*DTAU) 
      JS = (DLOG(S)-XMIN)/DX
      DX = (DLOG(S)-XMIN)/FLOAT(JS)
      ALPHA = R - DELTA - SIGMA**2/2.0
      P1 = SIGMA**2*DTAU/(2.0*DX**2) + ALPHA*DTAU/(2.0*DX)
      P2 = 1.0 - SIGMA**2*DTAU/DX**2
      P3 = 1.0 - P1 -P2
      P1 = P1/(1.0+R*DTAU)
      P2 = P2/(1.0+R*DTAU)
      P3 = P3/(1.0+R*DTAU)
      WRITE(6,*) 'P1,P2,P3',P1,P2,P3
      IF (P1.LT.0.0.OR.P2.LT.0.0.OR.P3.LT.0.0) STOP 'DECREASE DTAU'

      M = (XMAX-XMIN)/DX
      N = TAU/DTAU
      IF (M.GT.MS.OR.N.GT.NS) STOP 'INCREASE MS AND NS'
      DO J = 0, M
       VE(J) = MAX(K-DEXP(J*DX+XMIN),0.0)
       V(J) = VE(J)
      ENDDO

      BD(0) = K
      T(0) = 0.0      
      DO I = 1, N
       IEARLY = 0
       A = V(M)
       B = V(M-1)
       DO J = M-1, 1, -1
        VC = P1*A+P2*B+P3*V(J-1)
        IF (VC.LT.VE(J).AND.IEARLY.EQ.0) THEN
         BD(I) = DEXP(XMIN+J*DX)
         T(I) = DTAU*DFLOAT(I)
         IEARLY = 1
        ENDIF
        V(J) = MAX(VC, VE(J))
        A = B
        B = V(J-1)
       ENDDO
      ENDDO

      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Are you running it on a Windows computer?

Comment: yes I am,  atm working on updating the question

Comment: OK I won't post an answer yet then. Plz give info about which compiler you're using, also I can compile the example code (with FTN95) but can't run it because it needs EXP_DIFF.

Comment: Here is the entire code including EXP_DIFF [link](http://textuploader.com/d93kt)

Comment: @Thomas Kühn answers this very well but it might be worth having the link to using the command line prompt (if you're using FTN95) http://www.silverfrost.com/ftn95-help/devel/compiler_cmdline.aspx

Comment: Is this your alter-ego? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227430/frustrating-code-gives-bad-real-numer-in-item-1-of-list-input Two people with frustrating code in such a short time is strange.

Comment: File 5 is standard input.  File 6 is standard output.

Answer (score 1):

In the program, the line

```
WRITE(6,*) 'INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU'
```

is supposed to write out an instruction to the user. After that, the line

```
READ(5,*) S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU
```

waits for a list of comma separated values ending with a `RETURN`. So I would guess that this is intended behaviour. If you run the program, when you see the output

```
INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU
```

type in 7, comma-separated, values and the program will calculate the results for you.

If, on the other hand, you alter the original `WRITE` statement to

```
WRITE(6,*) S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU
```

you will get some random output, because the variables, whose values you are writing out, are at that point uninitialised.

**EDIT**:

The `WRITE` format is explained on many web pages in great detail. See for example [this one](http://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kley/lehre/ftn77/tutorial/format.html). In your specific case, there is a `WRITE` line and a `FORMAT` line, which together specify, how your output looks like:

```
      WRITE(2,10) T(I),BD(I)
      ...
10    FORMAT(1X,2F14.8)
```

`WRITE(2,10) T(I),BD(I)` writes the variables to file stream `2`(which you opened most likely with a command like this somewhere `open (unit = 2, file = "fort.2")`), with the format specified at line `10` (which is just two lines below the write statement). How the format specifiers work is explained in the link I provided.

**EDIT 2**:

As pointed out in the comments, `fort.2` is a standard name used by some fortran compilers if writing to stream nr. `2` without first using an `OPEN` statement. If you want to be sure that the code works correctly and set the filename yourself, use

```
OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE='myfile.txt')
```

Comment: that cleared up a lot actually! After I added 7, comma-separated, values , It created in the same directory a fort.2 file, what does that mean?

Comment: You somewhere open a file as `unit = 2` (presumably `fort.2`) to which you write in a `FOR` loop: `WRITE(2,10) T(I),BD(I)`. So without seeing everything, I'm guessing in `fort.2` you have a list of pairs of numbers. Did you try opening the file (maybe in a simple text editor)?

Comment: Yes I opened fort.2 and it does have a list of paris of numbers T(I),  BD(I).  but for every T(I),  BD(I) is supposed to take a  different value, however in the fort.2  , the BD(I) values are like step functions,  they don't change for many T(I) values, hmm..   Btw here is a link to the code: [link](http://textuploader.com/d93kt)

Comment: Well, if you don't understand that part, we can't really help you with the information given. I'm guessing that assignment of `T` and `BD` happens in `EXP_DIFF`, which you didn't provide. On the other hand, this goes quite far off your original question, so I'd suggest that you formulate a new question specifically for the results you get.

Comment: What does `WRITE(2,10)` mean? It doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: It writes to file 2, which you have not opened, so it creates fort.2 for that purpose.  It uses FORMAT statement 10 to format the output.

Comment: @Jack I did not know that `FORTRAN` automatically opens un-opened files with a standard name -- thanks for the info. I was assuming that he does that somewhere in the part he doesn't show.

Comment: fwiw the fort.n name is not actually standard. You should not count on it. I would only use that for lazy debugging code

Comment: @agentp so what about my last edit? Should I leave it as is, or correct it with a '(sometimes)'. Do you know which compilers include this feature and which not?

Comment: if you want to write to a file and know for sure what the name will be use an explicit `open` statement.

Comment: how would you suggest I use `open` ? I have tried `open(file=5.txt,*)` something like that, cant rmber.but that didn't help so much. My problem right now is that `BD(I)` Does not change for every iteration of `T(I)` , [link](http://textuploader.com/d93q4) , first column is `T(I)` and the second is `BD(I)`

Comment: Where in the code should i enter `OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE='myfile.txt')` ?

Comment: Preferably somewhere at the beginning of your program (or function, depending on the program structure), but latest before you write the first time.

Comment: i entered `OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE='myfile.txt')` just above `WRITE(6,*) 'INPUT S,K,TAU,SIGMA,R,DELTA,DTAU'` i created a myfile.txt in the same directory with the inputs written as 100.0d0,100.0d0,3.0d0,0.2d0,0.08d0,0.04d0,0.03d0

Answer (score 0):

BD(I) is changing step-wise because the calculation of it is in this IF test:

```
    IF (VC.LT.VE(J).AND.IEARLY.EQ.0) THEN
       BD(I) = DEXP(XMIN+J*DX)
       T(I) = DTAU*DFLOAT(I)
       IEARLY = 1
    ENDIF
```

From I=1 through I=10, that IF test succeeds when J=3.  When I=11, it succeeds when J=2, changing the calculation of BD(I).  When I=38, that IF test succeeds at J=1, and the calculation of BD(I) is changed again.